# how to replace the starting with minus value in a file with zero

Tags: awk, sed

I am having the text file as below. that file contains some negative data. so I want to replace that data with zero.

```
1,2,3
4,5,-6
7,-8,9
```

I have tried with below command.

```
sed 's/-*/0/g' 1.txt
```

but am not getting the reqired output. so can any one please help me on this.

Comment: `*` means match the preceding character zero or more times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'sub(/-./,"0")1' file
1,2,3
4,5,0
7,0,9
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed 's/-[0-9]\+/0/g' 1.txt
```

The way this works is, `sed` will find all sequences of characters that match the pattern `-[0-9]\+` and replace them with a `0`. Now, they meaning of the `-[0-9]\+` pattern is as follows: it will find a `-` character followed by a nonempty sequence of characters (this is the meaning of `\+`) that consists entirely of characters in the set between `0` and `9`.

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't it replace the negative number with 0? If not, what does happen?

Comment: @sivakumarV you need to be clear in describing what is not working.. the solution works perfectly fine when I checked on GNU sed.. just a guess, you might have different sed version.. while asking questions, it is advised to add that info in case it makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

You have to better understand regular expression for sed.
The expression `-*` in `s /-*/0/g` will match zero or more '-' characters. `*` in regular expression means zero or more duplicates, not wild character match, `.` does all character set match for a single character. See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html

To your question, you have to build a RE to match any negative number (maybe you need also consider float numbers). I would suggest:

```
-[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

This is an extended regular expression for sed program, meaning that starts with `-`, can with or without pre-dot numbers or dot, and must contain at least one number.

So

```
sed -r s/-[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/0/g 1.txt >2.txt
```

is what you need. `-r` option means use extended regular expression.

Some tests:

```
echo '12, 0.12, -2' | sed -r s/-[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/0/g
      12, 0.12, 0
echo '12, -234, -2' | sed -r s/-[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/0/g
      12, 0, 0
echo '-0.98, 2.34, -2' | sed -r s/-[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/0/g
          0, 2.34, 0
echo '-9.8, 0.34, -2' | sed -r s/-[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/0/g
         0, 0.34, 0
echo '-9.8, 1.34, -2' | sed -r s/-[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/0/g
         0, 1.34, 0
```

Hope this would be helpful, check tutors on http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html.

Thanks

Comment: @rojeeer, please quote your sed commands, ex: `sed -r 's/-[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/0/g' 1.txt >2.txt`

Comment: @sp asic oh really? I test in Ubuntu terminal, no quote is required. In my opinion, when running command, the argument will automiticlly be treated as string, you do not need quote, unless your argument may break the command, e.g., containing space, at this moment, quote argument. Thanks.

Comment: it cuts off `,9` from last line for OP's 3 line input.. on GNU sed 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

awk:

`$ awk 'gsub(/-[0-9]+/,0)1' 1.txt`

Identical to @redneb's sed solution but in awk. Replace all `-` starting number strings (`[0-9]+`) with a `0` in record $0 and print it nevertheless (`1`in the end).

Answer (score 0):

With awk, you would write

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i < 0) $i = 0; print}' file
```

My sed would be

```
sed -r 's/(^|,)-[^,]+/\10/g' file
```